# MySQL find last digit in colums using string function

Tags: mysql, string

I have to list all the details of a table where the colums event_id and horse_id end in a "1". I have achieved this by doing the following:

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE event_id AND show_id LIKE '%1'
```

However the question specifies the use of a string function. The only string i can find that would be useful in this case is RIGHT(). I can't get this to perform as i wish though.

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE RIGHT('1',1)
```

Displays all columns that end in a one. However i need to limit the search to event_id and horse_id.

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE event_id AND show_id RIGHT('1',1)
```

Doesn't work. The "right" string is invalid.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're *almost* there which is why I have no qualms about answering. If you'd just put your hand up for the answer, I'd be more reticent but, since you've done the bulk of the work (finding the `right()` function), here we go.

Firstly, `WHERE event_id AND show_id LIKE '%1'` almost certainly doesn't do what you think. Each component of a complex expression has to stand alone so you'd be looking at:

```
WHERE event_id LIKE '%1' AND show_id LIKE '%1'
```

However, that's still not using a string function. What they're getting at is that you should apply a string function to the column and compare that, something like:

```
... where right(event_id, 1) = '1' ...
```

The function `right(event_id, 1)` will return the rightmost character of the `event_id` column and you're simply comparing that to the literal `'1'`. Doing that with the `horse_id` as well (not the `show_id` as you seem to be doing in your example) will get you what you need.

**Stop reading now and try that first!**

---

And, if you *still* don't understand after reading that bit above and going away to test it, here's the thing you want. Don't use this without first trying to do it with the above information.

```
... where right(event_id, 1) = '1' and right(horse_id, 1) = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo! Appreciate the time taken to explain what was happening. And yes, i seemed to mix up the "show_id" and "horse_id" somewhere along the line.

Comment: `LIKE` is a string function, just an infix one... I'd have a hard time arguing to a student that they had got it wrong by doing `... LIKE '%1'`.

Comment: Actually, I would say `like` is an _operator,_ not a function. Just like `=` or `>`. Nobody ever refers to `=` and the equality function :-) In any case, unless you have reversed-data indexes (indexing on a column writ backwards), `like '%1'` is a very bad idea from a performance viewpoint. Probably doesn't matter here but it's something to look out for in general.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL Help to the rescue!

`RIGHT(str, n)` returns the the rightmost n characters from str. This means that you need to test against this return value.

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE RIGHT(event_id, 1) = '1' AND RIGHT(horse_id, 1) = '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE RIGHT(event_id, 1) = '1' AND 
      RIGHT(horse_id, 1) = '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
and substring(horse_id, -1) = '1'
```